# Where to get Beats with constant Temp

Tags: audio, samples, tempo

I am looking for audio samples with very distinct beats and with constant tempos, does anyone know where I can find them? The tempo of the audio samples should also be available.I am looking to use these samples to help develop a tempo detection and beat tracking application.

Comment: Does this question help? http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/5733/finding-high-quality-samples-for-music-production/5735#5735 or this:http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/where-can-i-find-free-sound-effects If not, let us know what that question lack by making your question more specific.

Comment: Sorry if the question isn't very clear.I am looking for Audio tracks that have their BPM given, and have a fairly constant BPM (i.e. their BPM does't change mid song).I want to use the Audio tracks to test a BPM detection and beat tracking tool.

Comment: It's clear alright. I linked to two questions which I think are relevant to you, maybe even containing answers that you can use. Did you check the answers on those question? For example ccmixter can search by BPM. On another note, a lot of popular electronic music has a constant tempo beat, wouldn't that be suitable for your use?

Comment: A lot of the Audio files given sounded like they had constant BPM's but unfortunately those BPM's weren't specified so they didn't prove very useful.I managed to get some useful audio from the second link because one of the sites given had some audio samples with constant, slow, easily computable BPM, so I tried to manually extract the BPM then use the audio file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to be using them to create a tempo detection program and need something constant Audacity has a great tool for creating metronome tracks.

1. If you haven't already download and install Audacity from http://audacity.sourceforge.net/
2. Open Audacity
3. Navigate to the menu Generate > Click Track
   [image: Audacity1]
4. Choose the tempo and other various setting you wish to set, the click track plug-in is fairly robust and it should do everything you are asking.

[image: click track settings]

However this will be very ideal tracks and will not have the full spectrum of sound as you would have with an actual audio track.

Comment: I didn't know Audacity could do this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to look at constant tempo songs only? Would your tempo detection work for constant tempo songs only? What would it do with non-constant songs?
Imho, one task of tempo detection would be to discriminate between constant and non-constant tempo songs.
TempoPlayer app for iOS categorizes songs by BPM and lets the user set his preferred "constancy limit".

Comment: I wanted to use the constant tempo songs to test if BPM detection works on the most basic cases, which are cases where there is a constant tempo.